# What are good references for the action of $\Gamma := \pi_1(S)$ on $S^1 = \partial \mathbb{H}^2$, where $S$ is a closed hyperbolic surface

Tags: reference-request, surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry, group-actions

To give some examples: what can we say about the action of $\Gamma$ on the set $V$ of points of $S^1$ that are not fixed for any element of $\Gamma$? Does there exist a Borel fundamental domain for the action of $\Gamma$ on $V$?

What can be said about orbits of this action?

I have added the ergodic theory label because maybe people expert in ergodic theory may provide good answers!

@ Glougloubarbaki

for a closed hyperbolic manifold the set $\Omega$ should be always empty..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action of $\Gamma$ on $S^1$ is ergodic with respect to the Lebesgue measure class on $S^1$, and the set of points fixed by elements of $\Gamma$ is countable. So no, there is no good notion of a fundamental domain for the action on $V$.

Comment: sorry I haven't understood your answer. What does it mean: "ergodic with respect to the Lebesgue measure class on S^1"? 
Who are the measure-preserving transformations (which are necessary in order to talk about ergodicity)?

Comment: @fritz: Given an action of a group $\Gamma$ on a space $X$ and a measure $\mu$ on $X$, one says that $\Gamma$ preserves the measure class of $\mu$ if for all $g \in \Gamma$ and all sets $A$ with $\mu(A)=0$ we have $\mu(g \cdot A) = 0$. So $\Gamma$ need not preserve the measure $\mu$, but since it preserves the measure class of $\mu$ one may still define ergodicity: $\Gamma$ is ergodic with respect to the measure class of $\mu$ if and only if every $\Gamma$-invariant measurable set either has $\mu$-measure equal to zero or its complement has $\mu$-measure equal to zero.

Comment: That's just what's going on for the action of $\Gamma$ on $S^1$ in this situation. $\Gamma$ preserves the measure class of Lebesgue measure on $S^1$, even though it does not preserve Lebesgue measure itself. In fact each element of $\Gamma$ acts as a diffeomorphism of $S^1$, which implies that sets of Lebesgue measure zero map to sets of measure zero. And, the action of $\Gamma$ is ergodic with respect to the measure class of Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 0):

The interesting question is the action on the largest open subset of the reals on which $\Gamma$ acts properly discontinuously (denote it by $\Omega$). Then 
$\mathbb{H} \cup \Omega/\Gamma$ is a complex Riemann surface with boundary.

$\Omega/\Gamma$ is called the ideal boundary of $S$. It may be empty. 
It plays an important role in Teichmüller theory, see e.g. the book by Gardiner and Lakic, "Quasiconformal Teichmüller theory".

In particular, whenever $\Omega \neq \mathbb R$, there is no nice fundamental domain on $\mathbb R$ for the action of $\Gamma$.

Comment: @fritz fair enough, I did not realize $\Omega$ was empty in the case you're interested in. then I suggest you look up literature on limit sets : basically, the dynamics is going to be complicated on $S^1$ in your case (chaotic in some sense). you can also look up Sullivan's dictionary : there is an analogy with the dynamics of rational maps preserving the unit disk (Blaschke products), and their Julia sets

Comment: more generally (it includes more general groups than your situation) you may want to read on Kleinian groups